# TreeView auto-selecting parent after user update selected child WPF command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a 2 level WPF treeview. When I click on a child item, the correct selectedCommand is triggered and all works well.

But when I click on my details view and update the field of this selected item, it unselect my childItem and fired the parent command because the parent is selected, but I need to just keep my childItem selected.

I have found some topics about the same problem, but I use command for my binding and not just code behind so I don't know how to make this solution work for me.

- Dispacher.BeginInvoke method : > [Parent TreeView Item ghost selected event!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314116/parent-treeview-item-ghost-selected-event)
- e.Handled : > [WPF TreeviewItem parent selected event fired after selecting a child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359617/wpf-treeviewitem-parent-selected-event-fired-after-selecting-a-child)
- And a topic that said it's a focus problem : [TreeView auto-selecting parent after user selects child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803233/treeview-auto-selecting-parent-after-user-selects-child)

Trigger of my command :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction
            Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My Treeview :

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type module:ParentViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
        <TextBlock Text="Parent"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type module:ChildViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=childName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                  
</TreeView>
```

And here is my command which is in my ViewModel file

```
public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
{
   get
   {
        return _itemSelectedCommand ?? (_itemSelectedCommand = new CommandHandler(param => SelectedCommand(param)));
   }
}

public void SelectedCommand(object selectedItem)
{
     //code to activate my details view with prism
    if(selectedItem.GetType().Name == "ParentType")
    { 
        ActivateParentView(); 
    }
    else 
    {
        ActivateDetailsView(.....); //activate child view
    }
}
```

So, I trigger the same command when selected an item in my treeview but when I select the child item, the parent event is also triggered so my command is triggered 2 times and activate my parent view and don't stay in my child view. How can I stop propagating the event if I have already pass through child command ? How can I make it working with my command and not in code behind ?

EDIT

---

Here is my function ActivateDetailsView() which is called by my SelectedCommand
I have 13 modules and I have one detailsView in each module, so when I click on my selected item, I will search using reflexivity for the view I need to activate and I use PRISM library to activate it.

```
private void ActivateDetailsView(string nameTypeItem,IRegion tabConfigurationRegion, ModuleItemBaseViewModel selectedItem)
    {
        try
        {
            string viewName = "ModuleItem" + nameTypeItem + "DetailsView";

            string moduleName = "Module" + nameTypeItem;
            string fullViewName = moduleName + ".Views." + viewName + ", " + moduleName;

            var typeOfCurrentView = Type.GetType(fullViewName);
            //var view = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfCurrentView);
            var view = tabConfigurationRegion.GetView(viewName);
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = _container.Resolve(typeOfCurrentView);

                // Add the view to the main region. This automatically activates the view too.
                tabConfigurationRegion.Add(view, viewName);
            }

            // The view has already been added to the region so just activate it.
            tabConfigurationRegion.Activate(view);

            string viewModelName = "ModuleItem" + nameTypeItem + "DetailsViewModel";
            string fullViewModelName = moduleName + ".ViewModels." + viewModelName + ", " + moduleName;

            var typeOfCurrentViewModel = Type.GetType(fullViewModelName);
            //equivalent to ModuleItemSiemensDetailsViewModel viewModelM = view.DataContext as ModuleItemSiemensDetailsViewModel;
            var propertyInfoDataContext = view.GetType().GetProperty("DataContext");
            var viewModelModuleItem = propertyInfoDataContext.GetValue(view, null);

            if (viewModelModuleItem != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = typeOfCurrentViewModel.GetProperty("CurrentModuleItem");

                //equivalent to viewModelModuleItem.CurrentModuleItem = selectedItem as ModuleItemBaseViewModel;
                prop.SetValue(viewModelModuleItem, selectedItem, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

**To reproduce the problem :** Start a new WPF project, Add one main project in your solution with a view with a treeview and a treeviewviewmodel with the list of ParentViewModel which will be display on your treeview. Define an other project with 2 viewmodels : one class ParentVM with an ObservableCollection and a childViewModel, let one or two property like name, and bind it to the treeview. In the second project, define a detailsView to see properties of your ChildViewModel. On your main project, in the treeviewviewmodel add a SelectedCommandFunction which use prism to activate your detailView. (You need to have a DetailsView when you click on the Parent and an other one when you click on the ChildView.

Comment: How exactly are you doing this: *"update the field of this selected item"*? As a workaround you can set flag to ignore future calls of this command (I guess with the use of `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` to reset it) during update.

Comment: I have a field directly bind on my ViewModelChild property. It raised an PropertyChangedEvent.  I will see your function !

Comment: You [can't bind to a field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11635199/1997232). Can you show the code? Ideally - make [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Problem could be simply in your code, but you don't show it. If it's a complicated issue, it will be much easier for others to help if they don't have to write everything on their own (read - start from reproducing the issue with your mcve).

Comment: I will not copy useless stuff here _Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem_ so my bindings are correct like `<StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentModuleItem.Name}" />
            </StackPanel>`. I will just add my real function which activate the view because it use PRISM for it and maybe it's the way I am using prism which is incorrect ...

Comment: I have also added a way to reproduce my issue with a new project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `TreeViewItem` is in the visual tree of its parent, and the event will bubble down, so if you clicked the tree leaf, and it has two parents, then the event will be called 3 times.

Ways to prevent this:

1. Bind the `IsSelected` of the `TreeItem` directly to `IsSelected` of your VM, and do your thing `OnPropertyChanged` of `IsSelected` property of your VM.
2. In a roundabout way: in codebehind, when you handle the event, check if the `OriginalSource` is the same as the sender (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209205/891715))
3. [Implement your own EventTrigger that marks events as Handled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7688249/891715)

Comment: That's not resolve my problem because it comes from a WPF issue with focus (more details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054052/8237280) but you perfectly answered my question and with this I found the root cause. So I will mark your solution as answer and just leave this link here for other people. Thank you for your help :)